# WPF VisualTreeHelper.HitTest using multiple threads

Tags: c#, multithreading, raycasting, inkcanvas, viewport3d

In my application, there is a transparent `InkCanvas` on top of a `Viewport3D` object. The `Viewport3D` shows a large 3D mesh. The user will sketch on the `InkCanvas` in order to select a portion of the 3D model that the `Viewport3D` is rendering. The user is allowed to draw circles on the `InkCanvas`.
When the user sketches, I iterate over all the points that fall inside of the drawn circle and I use the `VisualTreeHelper.HitTest` function to perform raycasting and determine which vertices of the `Viewport3D` mesh coincide with the sketch.

The problem is that `VisualTreeHelper.HitTest` is very slow. In case I used a `Parallel.For` I still would not be able to perform multiple raycastings on the Viewport3D in parallel (due to the fact that the owning thread of the `Viewport3D` object is the UI thread and I'd have to use `Viewport3D`'s `Dispatcher.Invoke` function which will defeat the purpose of having a `Parallel.For` in the first place.)

Is there a way to speed this up using multiple threads? Better yet, is there an alternative solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a lot of searching, I think what I want is impossible in the WPF framework. I switched to OpenTK for that purpose and implemented the raycasting myself.
Now I have a WPF-mimick in OpenTK with a much better performance. The code is [available here](https://github.com/Maghoumi/CodeFullToolkit) if anyone is interested.